# How to stream NSE option chain data into mathematica

Tags: import, data, web-access, streams, url

I'm trying to stream option chain data into mathematica from the

url: https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY

```
Import["https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"]/.Rule->List
```

I'm gettting the data however it's not streaming. If I use 'Dynamic', 'Refresh' with 'UpdateInterval' or run the 'Import' in loop every 1 sec, it's going to cost me 20-30 GB data per day (download rate is more that 1mbps) even though the size of the data is only 12KB.
This seems impractical.

Is there a way to check, if the data changed/updated at the source without downloading and download only when the data changed/updated at the source. For example if the "timestamp" (it's there in the data) could be accessed/read then it's possible to know exactly when the data is being changed/updated. Tried to use 'OpenRead' but unsuccessful.

I could give exact amount of 'Pause' in side the loop before 'Import' if the time interval for data update is fixed. Problem is data update interval is irregular.

Could anyone let me know how to remedy the situation.

Comment: `Import["https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY", "JSON"]`

Comment: "JSON" isn't working. It's stuck at 'Running...'

Comment: I tried with "DATA" , "CSV" , "Table" as well. Not working. Stuck at 'Running...'

Comment: It does work for me in V12.2, but sometimes returns an error, perhaps when data is updated. Check your internet connectivity setting in Mathematica, try importing other url

Comment: I see. I have mathematica 9. Internet connection is fine as it's working for Import["https://edms5.cern.ch/cedar/plsql/codes.list?initial=X&type=CODE&\code=EqCode"]

Comment: I was able to get the data through 'Import', however it's not streaming. If I use 'Dynamic' 'Refresh' with 'UpdateInterval' or run the 'Import' in loop every 1 sec, it's going to cost me 20-30 GB data per day (download rate is more that 1mbps). This seems impractical. Is there a way to check, if the data changed/updated at the source without downloading and download only when the data changed/updated at the source. For example if the "timestamp" (it's there in the data) could be accessed/read then it's possible to know exactly when the data is being changed/updated.

Comment: I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: "Is there a way to check, if the data changed/updated at the source and download only when the data changed/updated." There are several ways to do this via HTTP, but only if the server supports it. For instance, the [`If-Modified-Since`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since) header, or [Etags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag). Normally you would send a `HEAD` request and inspect the response headers, and then do a `GET` for the data if necessary. Whether this server supports one of these approaches is the real question.